# Hide the banner on top for entire session once user clicks on close in magento

Tags: javascript, php, html, magento-1.9

I have a banner which shows on the top of the webpage when the user is on our site

```
<div class="hidden-xs col-lg-12 header-banner">
<div class="text-secondary bigger-text>Get discount at checkout use promocode XXX<button class="btn btn-primary bannerCloseBtn" id="closeButton"> close</button></div>
</div>
```

I am trying to hide the banner when the user clicks on close button. This should not show up again until the session is over. How do i accomplish this in magento. The javascript for hiding the banner is

```
<script>
document.getElementById('closeButton').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
}, false);
</script>
```

Comment: @Zander, getElementById is vanilla javascript, you might be confused.

Comment: Well that part is working fine i want the state to remain like that until the session expires.

Comment: @Yashchaturvedi what about adding "style: display=jsFunction()" where you can check if there is a session active, otherwise return 'none'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a cookie, with no expiry date. This cookie usually gets removed when browser is closed.

This should work:

```
<script>
window.addEventListener('load', function(e){
    if(docuement.cookie.indexOf('banner_removed=1') !== -1)
        document.getElementById('closeButton').parentNode.style.display = 'none';
});
document.getElementById('closeButton').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
    document.cookie = "banner_removed=1";
}, false);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the solution is probably along these lines!

Comment: @Yashchaturvedi If my answer solved your problem, mark it as the correct answer.